# Using Microsoft Kinect with Opencv 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Hello I am trying to get disparity maps from a Microsoft kinect for xbox 360. I have opencv 3.0.0 and openni2 with libfreenect installed. When I run my code

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**){

    VideoCapture capture( CAP_OPENNI2 );
    namedWindow("win",1);

    for(;;){
        Mat depthMap;
        capture >> depthMap;
        imshow("win",depthMap);
        if( waitKey( 30 ) >= 0 ) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My kinect starts projecting the IR pattern but then I get a bunch of errors**

```
OpenNI2-FreenectDriver: Using libfreenect v0.5.3

OpenNI2-FreenectDriver: Found device freenect://0

OpenNI2-FreenectDriver: Opening device freenect://0

[Stream 70] Negotiated packet size 1920

write_register: 0x0105 <= 0x00

write_register: 0x0006 <= 0x00

write_register: 0x0012 <= 0x03

write_register: 0x0013 <= 0x01

write_register: 0x0014 <= 0x1e

write_register: 0x0006 <= 0x02

write_register: 0x0017 <= 0x00

[Stream 80] Negotiated packet size 1920

write_register: 0x000c <= 0x00

write_register: 0x000d <= 0x01

write_register: 0x000e <= 0x1e

write_register: 0x0005 <= 0x01

[Stream 70] Lost 2 total packets in 0 frames (inf lppf)

[Stream 70] Lost 5 total packets in 0 frames (inf lppf)

write_register: 0x0047 <= 0x00

OpenNI2-FreenectDriver: (ERROR) Unexpected size for XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (CvCapture_OpenNI2::readCamerasParams : Could not read virtual plane distance! ) in readCamerasParams, file /home/ubuntu/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_openni2.cpp, line 379 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): /home/ubuntu/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_openni2.cpp:379: error: (-2) CvCapture_OpenNI2::readCamerasParams : Could not read virtual plane distance! in function readCamerasParams

Aborted
```

Answer (score 1):

libfreenect a bug fixed required.

cd OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/src
     vim DepthStream.hpp

In **line 173**, the check for XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE expects a pDataSize of size unsigned long long.
  However, OpenNI2 expects an int32_t (size 8 vs size 4) so an error is in order. This error does not appear if
  if you use OpenNI2 or NiTE2 alone, since they don't ask for this property. However, if you use OpenCV+OpenNI2,
  the said property will be queried.

Fix. Change the case XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE with:

```
 case XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE:    // unsigned long long or unsigned int (for OpenNI2/OpenCV)

    if ( *pDataSize != sizeof(unsigned long long) && *pDataSize != sizeof(unsigned int) )
      { 
        LogError("Unexpected size for XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE!!!");
        return ONI_STATUS_ERROR;
      } else {
          if( *pDataSize == sizeof(unsigned long long) ) {
              *(static_cast<unsigned long long*>(data)) = ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE_VAL;
          } else {
              *(static_cast<unsigned int*>(data)) = (unsigned int) ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE_VAL;
          }
      return ONI_STATUS_OK;
       }
```

see [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~ahuaman3/docs/tutorials/software/source/perception.rst)