# OpenNI2 with OpenCV 3

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, openni

I'm on OSX 10.11.5

I have been trying to build OpenCV3 with OpenNI support. I have a Python script that is supposed to work with the XBox 360 Kinect, but OpenCV isn't detecting the Kinect. I have libfreenect installed and I can run freenect-glview which brings up the depth view.

I've done pretty extensive Google searches, but all guides seem to be for Windows or Linux. Can anyone help me? Guides for OpenNI 1 will work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Kinect for Xbox 360 on macOS successfully. The steps are as follows:

### 1) Install OpenNI2

```
$ brew tap homebrew/science

$ brew install openni2
```

### 2) Install [libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect)

> Note:
>     libfreenect for Kinect Xbox 360
>     libfreenect2 for Kinect Xbox One

Because of this issue: [Using Microsoft Kinect with Opencv 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657103/using-microsoft-kinect-with-opencv-3-0-0), we should build it by ourselves.

#### 2.1) Download

```
$ curl -O -L https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/archive/v0.5.5.tar.gz
$ tar zxf v0.5.5.tar.gz
$ cd libfreenect-0.5.5/
```

#### 2.2) Fix issue

```
# jump to line 173
$ vi OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/src/DepthStream.hpp

        case XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE:    // unsigned long long or unsigned int (for OpenNI2/OpenCV)
          if (*pDataSize != sizeof(unsigned long long) && *pDataSize != sizeof(unsigned int))
          {
            LogError("Unexpected size for XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE");
            return ONI_STATUS_ERROR;
          } else {
            if (*pDataSize != sizeof(unsigned long long)) {
              *(static_cast<unsigned long long*>(data)) = ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE_VAL;
            } else {
              *(static_cast<unsigned int*>(data)) = (unsigned int) ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE_VAL;
            }
          }
          return ONI_STATUS_OK;
```

#### 2.3) Build

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER=ON
$ make
```

#### 2.4) Install

```
$ export OPENNI2_DIR=$(python -c 'import subprocess, glob; \
prefix = subprocess.check_output("brew --prefix", shell=True); \
print(glob.glob("%s/Cellar/openni2/*" % prefix[:-1])[0])')
$ cd lib/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/
$ export FREENECT_DRIVER_LIB=libFreenectDriver.dylib
$ export FREENECT_DRIVER_LIB=$(python - <<'EOF'
import os
lib = os.environ['FREENECT_DRIVER_LIB']
while os.path.islink(lib):
    lib = os.readlink(lib)
print(lib)
EOF
)
$ ln -sf `pwd`/$FREENECT_DRIVER_LIB $OPENNI2_DIR/lib/ni2/OpenNI2/Drivers/libFreenectDriver.dylib
$ ln -sf `pwd`/$FREENECT_DRIVER_LIB $OPENNI2_DIR/share/openni2/tools/OpenNI2/Drivers/
```

#### 2.5) Preview

```
$ cd `brew --prefix`/share/openni2/tools
$ ./NiViewer
```

### 3) Build OpenCV

#### 3.1) Python

```
$ brew install python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13

$ pip install numpy
```

#### 3.2) Source

```
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv/
$ git checkout 3.2.0

# if use extra modules
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
$ cd opencv_contrib/
$ git checkout 3.2.0
```

#### 3.3) Build

```
$ cd opencv/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/

$ export PY_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
$ export PY_NUMPY_DIR=$(python -c 'import os.path, numpy.core; print(os.path.dirname(numpy.core.__file__))')

$ export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include/ni2
$ export OPENNI2_REDIST=/usr/local/lib/ni2

$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
\
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
-DPYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=$PY_HOME/bin/python \
-DPYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=$PY_HOME/Headers \
-DPYTHON2_LIBRARY=$PY_HOME/lib \
-DPYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
-DPYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$PY_NUMPY_DIR/include/ \
\
-DWITH_OPENNI2=ON \
\
-DBUILD_DOCS=OFF \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
\
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
..

$ make -j$(python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print(mp.cpu_count())')
$ make install
```

### 4) Finally

I posted the details to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/joinAero/2bf53de4031ffcf8ed72208f486ed659). Samples here: [C++](https://gist.github.com/joinAero/40f2bf867b8d7beed2d2c5de3b6f933a), [Python](https://gist.github.com/joinAero/1f76844278f141cea8338d1118423648).

> NOTE: Unable to retrieve correct image using Python code now. Please see this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4735).